# Reference for representations of quaternion group

Tags: rt.representation-theory

To satisfy a referee, I need a reference for the following well-known fact (which is not hard to prove, but it seems silly to prove it in a paper).  I can't find it in either Serre or Fulton-Harris's books on representation theory.  Can anyone provide me a reference?

Let $Q$ be the $8$-element quaternion group, so we have a central extension
$$1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2 \longrightarrow Q \longrightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/2)^2 \longrightarrow 1.$$
Then the following constitute a complete list of irreducible representations of $Q$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

1. One-dimensional representations that factor through $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$.
2. A four-dimensional representation $W$ obtained from the left action of $Q$ on the real quaternions (viewed as a $4$-dimensional real vector space).

I remark that the representation $W$ is irreducible but not absolutely irreducible -- when we extend the field of scalars to $\mathbb{C}$, it breaks up into two copies of the (unique) two-dimensional irreducible complex representation.

Comment: I much prefer to write (and read) papers that are as self-contained as possible... So it doesn't seem at all silly to reprove a well-known fact if it is useful and relevant. Given that the fact you mention can be proved in 2 lines - as per the answers below - that seems a much better solution to me than providing a reference.

Comment: Gill! I didn't know you were on MO. Well everybody is, I suppose. Hope you're well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Q_8$ is an extraspecial group, if you want you can say that the result follows from Quillen's classification of their real representations in

Quillen, The mod 2 cohomology rings of extra-special 2-groups and the spinor groups

Mathematische Annalen, 1971

Comment: Where exactly is this done in Quillen's paper?

Comment: As a reader, I would prefer not to have this result referred to that paper which is probably a few hundred orders of magnitude more complicated that the result itself! 

Comment: @darij grinberg: this is Proposition 5.8 in Quillen's paper.
@Mariano: it is my understanding that the only point is to satisfy a referee :) And yes, even understanding the notation takes longer than proving the result for oneself, but hey, somebody asked for a reference.

Comment: There were a number of great answers, but I really like the passive-aggressive quality of this one :).

Answer (score 10):

This example is elementary (close to an exercise), which does make it tempting just to write a couple of lines of explanation in a paper.   But including such a "proof" without further comment tends to leave the impression that the ideas were just discovered.   It's easy to refer to an older textbook such as I.M. Isaacs *Character Theory of Finite Groups* (now an AMS reprint): Exercise (2.4) combined with page 145 on the real case.   The easy fact, usually just stated without comment, is that the complex linear characters of a finite group are those of the quotient by the derived group (here a Klein 4-group).   But the real case needs an explicit reminder.

There's no magic way to deal with "well-known" facts (if they are indeed well-known), but here it's easy to give in to a referee request without inflating the paper.  By the way, neither Serre nor Fulton-Harris pretends to be as comprehensive a reference for finite group characters as the books by Curtis-Reiner and Isaacs.

Answer (score 4):

It seems easier simply to supply a proof of two lines. Th unique two dimensional complex representation $V$ is not a real representation, so the direct sum of $V$ and $V\simeq {\overline V}$ is defined over ${\mathbb R}$. By dimension count, you have the four characters (four one dimensional real representations), and this irreducible four dimensional one; so this gives the dimension of the group algebra over ${\mathbb R}$ (namely $8$).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a stupid proof which, I think, would not elicit any further questions:

Let $\left[1\right]$, $\left[-1\right]$, $\left[i\right]$, $\left[-i\right]$, $\left[j\right]$, $\left[-j\right]$, $\left[k\right]$, $\left[-k\right]$ be the elements of $Q$ which correspond to $1$, $-1$, $i$, $-i$, $j$, $-j$, $k$, $-k$ under the canonical embedding $Q\subseteq \mathbb H^{\times}$. Then, the $\mathbb R$-linear map $\mathbb H\oplus \mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R$ which sends every $\left(a+bi+cj+dk,e,f,g,h\right)$ to

$\dfrac{\left[1\right]-\left[-1\right]}{2}\left(a+b\left[i\right]+c\left[j\right]+d\left[k\right]\right) $
$+ \dfrac{\left[1\right]+\left[-1\right]}{2}\left(\left(e+f+g+h\right)\left[1\right]+\left(e-f-g+h\right)\left[i\right]+\left(e+f-g-h\right)\left[j\right]+\left(e-f+g-h\right)\left[k\right]\right)$

(for all reals $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, $g$, $h$) is easily seen to be an $\mathbb R$-algebra isomorphism. Now, the representation theory of a direct product of algebras is well-known, and so is the representation theory of fields.

Comment: The algebra $\mathbb RQ_8$ is semisimple. Since there are $|Q_8/Q_8'|=4$ modules of degree $1$ and the tautological representation on $\mathbb H$ is irreducible and has $\mathbb H$ as its endomorphism ring, as one can see at once, the wedderburn factorization *must* be $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times\times\mathbb H$, for there is no room for anything else.